# Updating Status Strip on Form from BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback

I am currently taking an existing design and refactoring certain aspects of it.  I am attempting to wrap the BackgroundWorker class in a separate object and invoke the data import on a separate thread.  My only issue is getting the StatusStrip object to update on the Form.  The application uses Reflections and I have considered this when wrapping the import routine.  I have eliminated all cross threading to this point.  I have redirected the callback for updating the StatusStrip from the Form into this wrapper object and the data import is calling back to the wrapper.  There is a Method in the form for the purposes of handling the original callback.  I just have to figure out how to Invoke the update across threads.

The Asynchronous operation part is working due in large part to the information I have garnered from stackoverflow.  It's all wired up with exception to this silly StatusStrip.

Comment: Perhaps `Form.Invoke()`?

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I have not tried that!  Does that require a delegate?

Comment: Additionally, I have a reference to my Main Form in this wrapper when I instance it.  But, to my dismay, the BackgroundWorker gives me grief when I attempt to use the variable that contains the Form object.

Comment: Yes, it does require a delegate.  So, you your reference to your main form and call Invoke, passing the delegate to the code that will update the StatusStrip.

Comment: Aha!  This is the part that I am having trouble with - wiring that delegate.  It is an event in the Form that the data import is passed to call back to.  Any suggestions where I might place this delegate and how to intertwine the new delegate with the existing event?

Comment: This will show you how to do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls

Comment: Thanks, Jon.  The delegate in the Form object that hooks into the updateStatus event appears to not be available in my BackgroundWorker wrapper.  I'm scratching my head...  but, it appears to be that I am going in the correct direction...  there's just some little hitch that I am missing????

Comment: private void updtStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MainForm.InvokeRequired)
            { MainForm.Invoke(MainForm.updtStatBar, new object[] { sender, e }); }
            
        }

Comment: This is the piece I have currently in my BackgroundWorker class that is the event the data import is calling back to.  Insider here is where I want to invoke the callback to the UI thread.  The delegate in the Form class is not available and the updtStaBar event is not allowed to be used in this manner.  I know that I am 2 seconds from the answer...  I just can't figure out where to place the plug into the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it worked out.

In the event that is called back to in the BackgroundWorker wrapper class I did the following as per Nick's suggestion:

```
private void updtStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { if (MainForm.InvokeRequired)
      { MainForm.Invoke(new DoUIWorkHandler(MainForm.updtStatus), new object[] { sender, e }); }
    }
```

Note: MainForm.updtStatus is the original event on the Form that was called back to by the data import to update the StatusStrip.

I found on another stackoverflow thread this:

```
public delegate void DoUIWorkHandler();
```

And, I modified the delegate for my code at the top of the BackgroundWorker wrapper:

```
public delegate void DoUIWorkHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
```

This was the delegate piece that I was missing!  Works like a charm!  Thanks for all your help in this matter.